# Unable to finalize Container Registry Transition to Artifact Repository

Tags: google, gcloud

I tried to create a Container Registry and it asked me to upgrade to the Artifact repository. When I tried to transition, the Finalize button did not work. It keeps on loading and loading. I tried using Safari and Chrome but was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug. It occurred to me also, but through the CLI it worked:

```
gcloud beta artifacts settings finalize-upgrade-redirection \
    --project=<YOUR_PROJECT>
```